# Will the Ride Request Widget deprecation affect the REST API Uber exposes?

Tags: rest, uber-api

I've recently seen this message:

> This product is deprecated and will no longer be supported on May 31st, 2018. If you are starting a new project you should use deep links to m.uber.com. See the migration guide on how to link to the latest Uber rider experience. 
>   [Here's a screenshot of this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3s1d.png)

Keeping in mind that this widget offers these functionalities(as does the REST API):

> Selecting a service (e.g., uberX, UberBlack, etc.)
>   Specifying pickup and dropoff locations
>   Viewing time and price estimates
>   Requesting a ride

Will the [Rest API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api) be somehow affected by this change?

Will I be able to further make requests like these ones?

GET /v1.2/estimates/price
GET /v1.2/history
GET /v1.2/places/{place_id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Uber representative, and I really kind of feel that asking support from a vendor is the way to go for a vendor specific thing. However, when I read that message and screenshot they are clearly talking about a widget, not a REST api.

Comment: Thanks for the response Evert. You are correct. The widget is being deprecated, it will not impact the API or those endpoints.